# How to present view over current view with transparency

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, uiview, uiviewcontroller

I have an `UIViewController` (further 'UIVC') with lot of code and I need to present another view (score table) over it, which by itself also has a bunch of code and its view designed using IB so it has its own IB connections too. So I decided to split it to two `UIViewControllers`, which is pretty obvious. Everything works fine but still I need to present my score table not like another `UIViewController` but just like an usual `UIView` to make it half transparent so user could see whats happening in the main `UIVC` through the score table view (due to its tranparency). Moreover, I need to make the code in main `UIVC` still run.
Pretty example is Counter Strike game (and many others), when you press TAB key in the game you can see the score table but it doesn't hold the game and you are able to see whats happening in game.
I was thinking that I could achieve it using `presentModalViewController` (like Game Center) but I can't make it transparent so I cant see `UIVC` in the background. Like I said score table has its own code and many IBOutlets aswell and I'd like to separate it out from main `UIVC` code.
So how to achieve my needs? (Separate out score table's code, make it transparent and don't intterupt executing main `UIVC's` code). My app insn't cocoa its just usual app
What I did try: tried to make score table's `UIView` background of `[UIColor clearColor]` while presenting it as modalVC. No luck. Additionally I tried to uncheck `UIView's` opaque property - no luck. Tried to set `UIView's` alpha to .5 - still no luck. Also tried to make self.navigationController.view.hidden=YES, no luck. Can't see main UIVC "picture". Also I tried to set all subviews alpha to .2 in score table but it still shows me white non transparent screen.

Answer (score 0):

See if this works, its to display transparent view controllers but is the same concept. [Here](https://gist.github.com/1301978)

However I'm not entirely sure if your first view controller will remain visible.

Comment: I'm afraid provided code snipplet just adds UIViewController's view to main UIVC but what about executing presenting UIVC code?

Comment: Moreover what about IB connections?

Comment: Have you tried using 1 view controller, and placing two views inside of it and just set 1 of the views as hidden while you're not using it.

Comment: thats exactly what I did finally. c my own answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Even if you you the trickto present the second viewcontroller with half transparancey you can not see the first viewcontroller beyond the second one.Presented model view contorller are supposed to be opaque in IOS.

I have the same situation with a small tableview with transparentbackground margins.I ended up crating a UIView class taht holds the tableview.I wrote two methods inside this UIview namely

```
-(void)presentTransparentViewin(UIView*)view;

-(void)removeViewwithAnimation;
```

It sounds like a bad programming practive to implement delegate methods of UITableview in Uiview bad works fine.

Answer (score 0):

just for your requirement just setAlphs of view like bellow in `viewDidLoad:`

```
[self.view setAlpha:0.5];// set alpha with your requirement
```

and from your UIVC view just call this method when you want to display view

Here good if you paste this bellow method in `AppDelegate` and call with `AppDelegate` object

Create object of `yourViewController` like bellow in `AppDelegate.h` like bellow..

```
yourViewController *yourViewController;
```

and use in bellow method..

```
-(void)addMakeOfferView{

   yourViewController=[[yourViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"yourViewController" bundle:nil];
    objMakeOfferView.view.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.3, 1.3);
    objMakeOfferView.view.alpha = 0;
    [UIView animateWithDuration:.35 animations:^{
        objMakeOfferView.view.alpha = 0.94;
        objMakeOfferView.view.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1, 1);
    }];
    objMakeOfferView.view.frame=CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480);
    [self.window addSubview:objMakeOfferView.view];
}
```

and call from your `UIVC` class like bellow..

```
AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
[appDelegate addMakeOfferView];
```

Comment: I have to level up my knowledge to understand such technique :) Really why involving appDelegate here? Thanx anyway

Comment: @Stan wel-come dude but i use this logic when requirement to show small view  with transition of background view so i develop this code and worked it as my requirement.. :)

Answer (score 0):

Best option I discovered is to create custom class by extending UIView (not UIViewController) and desing its view in IB. Then I set FileOwner to my class name in IB, set up all IB connections, wrote (copypasted :) actually) needed methods to display scores. 
Tricky part was in using initWithCoder/awakefromNib methods especially initWithCoder where I need to load my nib and the main thing is to add its view via previously set up IB connection. That is not only all needed subviews has to be IB connected but the (parent/root)view by itself aswell.

```
    - (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder {
    if ((self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder]))
    {
        [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:NSStringFromClass([self class]) owner:self options:nil];

        [self addSubview:vwTopLevelView]; //vwTopLevelView is the IB link to parent view
// without adding vwTopLevelView it always loads empty view so you just wont c it
// but all IB links will be valid, image view will have their images loaded etc
    }
    return self;
}
```

Then I just added the new score table view to the main UIVC, checked its property as hidden and set the class from UIView to my class. Now score table loads with main UIVC but it is hidden and I just need to call 1 method to fill it with data and then just make it's hidden=NO and voilla... And the view.background is of clearColor so I got the transparency.
This way I have separated out score table's code and IB outlets to another class (UIView ext) and its view is transparent enough and since its not UIViewController the code of my main UIVC doesn't hold.